# prohibit use dot,plus,minus,e when input type number in semantic ui react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

it is necessary to prohibit the use of a dot, plus, minus, e in the input from the semantic-ui-react library, I was looking for answers, but they do not work, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify the context of your question: what input are you using, what have you tried that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex with your input

```
/[.+-]|[e]/
```

`[.+-]` => is checking for special characters dot, plus, minus

`[e]` => checking for character e

Comment: can you ask for a complete example of how to stop typing in input, if it does not coincide with regex?